# Independence of random variables given an event

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, independence

Suppose we have independence of two random variables, $X$ and $Y$. This of course then implies that $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)$ where $p(x,y)$ is the joint pmf of X and Y (ie. $p(x,y) = P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x)P(Y=y) = p(x)p(y)$.

This may be silly, but that does this imply that $P(X=x, Y=y | Z=z) = P(X=x | Z=z)*P(Y=y | Z=z)$, where Z is an arbitrary random variable?

My first thought would be yes, because given Z=z, X and Y should still be independent. However, when trying to prove this, I found:
$P(X=x , Y=y | Z=z) = \frac{P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)}{P(Z=z)} = \frac{P(X=x|Y=y,Z=z)P(Y=y,Z=z)}{P(Z=z)}=P(X=x|Y=y,Z=z)P(Y=y|Z=z)$.

So where I'm having trouble is the last step, can we remove the conditioning of Y=y on the left side of the product given X is independent of Y?

Note:
This is not a homework problem or anything, but rather I tried to make the assumption that this was correct in another proof I was doing and was concerned about the validity.

Answer (score 1):

No. The relation $P(X,Y\mid Z) = P(X \mid Z) P(Y \mid Z)$ means that $X$ and $Y$ are [conditionally independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) given $Z$, and that is not implied by independence of $X$ and $Y$, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22407/independence-and-conditional-independence-between-random-variables).

Comment: Okay this is very interesting. So I assume that this is because P(X|Y,Z)=P(X|Z) is not necessarily true if X and Y are independent?

Comment: Yes, in general you have $P(X \mid Y, Z) = P(X \mid Z) \alpha(Y, Z)$, where $\alpha(Y, Z) = P(Y\mid X, Z) / P(Y\mid Z)$

Answer (score 1):

It does not work.

---

E.g. let $Z$ be prescribed by $\omega\mapsto1$ if $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ and $\omega\mapsto 0$ otherwise.

If $x\neq y$ then: $$P(X=x,Y=y\mid Z=1)=0$$ but it is quite well possible that: $$P(X=x\mid Z=1)P(Y=y\mid Z=1)>0$$